# How to tag subnets when using module vpc

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file, terraform0.12+

```
module "vpc" {
  source             = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version            = "2.33.0"
  name               = "${local.env_name}-vpc"
  public_subnets     = data.template_file.public_cidrsubnet[*].rendered
  private_subnets    = data.template_file.private_cidrsubnet[*].rendered

tags = merge(local.common_tags, { Name = "${local.env_name}-vpc" })
```

Creating is successful but only problem is tagging, for all the newly created using module vpc  tag is "default-vpc"

I wanted to tag each resource separately, like private-subnet, public-subnet etc.

Comment: Can you provide the local file as well

Comment: in local it have just some billing tags and environment type as dev

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this question. It is now possible to supply `public_subnet_tags` as noted in the [documentation for VPC in Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest).

Answer (score 0):

Create the subnet separately and assign it to the vpc

```
resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
    vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id
    cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
    tags = {
        Name = "Main"
    }
}
```